# Centered elements in cssmenu

Tags: html, css

I've got this css code...

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  background: #333333;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 17px;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 23px;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
  height: 35px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.15);
  padding: 11px 15px;
  width: 170px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  font-weight: 400;
  background: #333333;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.last-item > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  right: auto;
  left: 11px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  right: auto;
  left: 14px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 17px;
  height: 0;
}
@media all and (max-width: 768px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #cssmenu {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-center > ul {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li {
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li,
  #cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
    height: auto;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li {
    float: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 25px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 35px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    color: #dddddd;
    background: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li.active > a {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
  #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before,
  #cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
  #cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button {
    display: block;
    padding: 17px;
    color: #dddddd;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    right: 17px;
    display: block;
    height: 4px;
    width: 20px;
    border-top: 2px solid #dddddd;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    right: 17px;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 20px;
    background: #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button.menu-opened:after {
    top: 23px;
    border: 0;
    height: 2px;
    width: 15px;
    background: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button.menu-opened:before {
    top: 23px;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 15px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
    height: 46px;
    width: 46px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened {
    background: #262626;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button {
    height: 34px;
    width: 34px;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    right: 19px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 2px;
    display: block;
    background: #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:after {
    top: 15px;
    right: 13px;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after {
    background: #ffffff;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 19px;
    right: 22px;
    display: block;
    width: 2px;
    height: 8px;
    background: #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:before {
    top: 12px;
    right: 16px;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:before {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

...and this html code:

```html
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
   <li class='active'><a href='#'>Products</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'>Product 1</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
               <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href='#'>Product 2</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
               <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I haven't written this code so I'd like to know how do I get the elements in the menu to be centered in the menu itself? Can I get rid of the blank space on the left and on the right of the menu?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to apply the `text-align: center` style to your `<ul>` and replace `float: left` with `display: inline-block`for your `<li>`'s, like this:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  background: #333333;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 17px;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 23px;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
  height: 35px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.15);
  padding: 11px 15px;
  width: 170px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  font-weight: 400;
  background: #333333;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.last-item > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  right: auto;
  left: 11px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  right: auto;
  left: 14px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 17px;
  height: 0;
}
@media all and (max-width: 768px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #cssmenu {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-center > ul {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li {
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li,
  #cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
    height: auto;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li {
    float: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 25px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 35px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    color: #dddddd;
    background: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li.active > a {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
  #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before,
  #cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
  #cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button {
    display: block;
    padding: 17px;
    color: #dddddd;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    right: 17px;
    display: block;
    height: 4px;
    width: 20px;
    border-top: 2px solid #dddddd;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    right: 17px;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 20px;
    background: #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button.menu-opened:after {
    top: 23px;
    border: 0;
    height: 2px;
    width: 15px;
    background: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button.menu-opened:before {
    top: 23px;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 15px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
    height: 46px;
    width: 46px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened {
    background: #262626;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button {
    height: 34px;
    width: 34px;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    right: 19px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 2px;
    display: block;
    background: #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:after {
    top: 15px;
    right: 13px;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after {
    background: #ffffff;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 19px;
    right: 22px;
    display: block;
    width: 2px;
    height: 8px;
    background: #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:before {
    top: 12px;
    right: 16px;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:before {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>Home</a>

        </li>
        <li class='active'><a href='#'>Products</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href='#'>Product 1</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href='#'>Product 2</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>About</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Contact</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d67e7f7f/5/embedded/result/)**.

If you want to get rid of the empty left/right space in your navigation menu then you should use the above styles and along with that, apply a `width` to the `#cssmenu` div and center your menu using `margin: 0px auto`, like this:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400, 700);
 #cssmenu, #cssmenu ul, #cssmenu ul li, #cssmenu ul li a, #cssmenu #menu-button {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 1;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu:after, #cssmenu > ul:after {
    content:".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
    display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    background: #333333;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
    font-size: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
    text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
    float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
    padding: 17px;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #dddddd;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
    padding-right: 30px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    right: 11px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 2px;
    display: block;
    background: #dddddd;
    content:'';
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 19px;
    right: 14px;
    display: block;
    width: 2px;
    height: 8px;
    background: #dddddd;
    content:'';
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    -o-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
    top: 23px;
    height: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
    text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
    height: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    -o-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul {
    left: auto;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li:hover > ul {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
    height: 35px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
    margin-left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.15);
    padding: 11px 15px;
    width: 170px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #dddddd;
    font-weight: 400;
    background: #333333;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a, #cssmenu ul ul li.last-item > a {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a, #cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    right: 11px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 2px;
    display: block;
    background: #dddddd;
    content:'';
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
    right: auto;
    left: 11px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 13px;
    right: 14px;
    display: block;
    width: 2px;
    height: 8px;
    background: #dddddd;
    content:'';
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    -o-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
    right: auto;
    left: 14px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
    top: 17px;
    height: 0;
}
@media all and (max-width: 768px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #cssmenu {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #cssmenu ul {
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
    }
    #cssmenu.align-center > ul {
        text-align: left;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li {
        width: 100%;
        border-top: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li, #cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
        height: auto;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li a, #cssmenu ul ul li a {
        width: 100%;
        border-bottom: 0;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li {
        float: none;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li a {
        padding-left: 25px;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
        padding-left: 35px;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li a {
        color: #dddddd;
        background: none;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a, #cssmenu ul ul li.active > a {
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul, #cssmenu ul ul ul, #cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: left;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after, #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before, #cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after, #cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
        display: none;
    }
    #cssmenu #menu-button {
        display: block;
        padding: 17px;
        color: #dddddd;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
    #cssmenu #menu-button:after {
        position: absolute;
        top: 22px;
        right: 17px;
        display: block;
        height: 4px;
        width: 20px;
        border-top: 2px solid #dddddd;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #dddddd;
        content:'';
    }
    #cssmenu #menu-button:before {
        position: absolute;
        top: 16px;
        right: 17px;
        display: block;
        height: 2px;
        width: 20px;
        background: #dddddd;
        content:'';
    }
    #cssmenu #menu-button.menu-opened:after {
        top: 23px;
        border: 0;
        height: 2px;
        width: 15px;
        background: #ffffff;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    #cssmenu #menu-button.menu-opened:before {
        top: 23px;
        background: #ffffff;
        width: 15px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
    #cssmenu .submenu-button {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 99;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        display: block;
        border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
        height: 46px;
        width: 46px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened {
        background: #262626;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button {
        height: 34px;
        width: 34px;
    }
    #cssmenu .submenu-button:after {
        position: absolute;
        top: 22px;
        right: 19px;
        width: 8px;
        height: 2px;
        display: block;
        background: #dddddd;
        content:'';
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:after {
        top: 15px;
        right: 13px;
    }
    #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after {
        background: #ffffff;
    }
    #cssmenu .submenu-button:before {
        position: absolute;
        top: 19px;
        right: 22px;
        display: block;
        width: 2px;
        height: 8px;
        background: #dddddd;
        content:'';
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:before {
        top: 12px;
        right: 16px;
    }
    #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:before {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>Home</a>

        </li>
        <li class='active'><a href='#'>Products</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href='#'>Product 1</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href='#'>Product 2</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>About</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Contact</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d67e7f7f/6/embedded/result/)**.

Comment: @user2359928 You're welcome. Please also check my updated answer above to know how to remove the extra space on the left/right. Moreover, please mark my answer as the correct one so that users can know that your query has been answered. Thank you.

Comment: I tried it and to get rid of the right border I have to put a width % higher than 100 but the left margin doesn't disappear. How can I solve?

Comment: @user2359928 Can you show an example? I am sorry but I am unable to understand it this way. By the way, there's a also a horizontal padding added to your `ul li a` items which you can try reducing.

Comment: ok, if I try writing something like this:

#cssmenu {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  background: #000000;                   
  width: 103%;
    margin: 10px auto;

the right blank border of the page disappers but the left doesn't and also the menu is not centered anymore.

Comment: @user2359928 That's because when you add `width: 103%` to `#cssmenu`, it's width exceeds outside of the container width and it no longer remains centered. You actually need to use a width lesser than `100%`. If you take a look at this example (http://jsfiddle.net/d67e7f7f/6/embedded/result/), you can see that I've set the `width` of `#cssmenu` to `40%`.

Comment: I saw it but 40% gives me a larger border, I'm sorry if I'm bothering you but I can't sort it out

Comment: @user2359928 Not a problem at all. I think I understand your issue, do you want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/32jm8rot/embedded/result/?

Comment: Not exactly, I mean the border of the page not of the menu, to make you understand go to http://apple.com and look at the top menu bar, the gray covers everything from left to right, that's what I'm trying to get.

Comment: Oh I see, you will need to remove any padding/margin acting on the `#cssmenu` element like this: http://jsfiddle.net/d67e7f7f/7/embedded/result/. In this fiddle, I've removed the `margin: 8px;` which is assigned to the `body` tag by default.